# Event Viewer and failing disk

Tags: windows-10, event-viewer

I've noticed several problems during copying files to external drive e.g. sometimes copying ends up with message about problem during writing/reading (I do not know exact message sorry) then I had to retry copy given file unless it is copied. I've noticed in Event Viewer following event IDs:

```
51 - An error was detected on device \Device\Harddisk1\DR12 during a paging operation.

140 - The system failed to flush data to the transaction log. Corruption may occur in VolumeId: D:, DeviceName: \Device\HarddiskVolume20.
(A device which does not exist was specified.)

157 - Disk 1 has been surprise removed.

26 - Description: Windows - Delayed Write Failed : Windows was unable to save all the data for the file \Device\HarddiskVolume4\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL$INSTANCETWO\LOG\ERRORLOG. The data has been lost. This error may be caused by a failure of your computer hardware or network connection.

7 - The device, \Device\Harddisk2\DR2, has a bad block.
```

Is my hard drive failing? If yes what is the recommended way to rescue data?
Should I check for another event IDs?

EDIT:
The disk is External Samsung D3 2TB, and here comes the output from utility called [HDDscan](http://hddscan.com/) (smartctl and HDtune were not able to read SMART data from the disk):

[image]

Comment: Possible hard disk failure. Check your hard drives for SMART errors [How can I read my hard drive's SMART status in Windows 7?](//superuser.com/q/29240), and [What is the easiest method of checking SMART status for your hard drive?](//superuser.com/q/14803). Report back with the results.

Comment: [How do I recover lost/inaccessible data from my storage device?](//superuser.com/q/241817)

Comment: @DavidPostill I've uploaded SMART data. Thanks for any help.

Comment: I can't see anything obviously wrong.

Comment: @DavidPostill do you have any idea what else should I try?

Comment: Sorry, no more ideas.

Answer (score -1):

In "File Explorer", if you right-click the drive in "This PC" and open "Properties", there's a tab called "Tools" with an option to "...check the drive for file system errors".

I'd also copy the data off, look for updated firmware from the drive manufacturer, reformat the drive and then copy the data back. Then continue monitoring for errors.